# Autenticar usuario y enviar notificaciones con Firebase

Tags: firebase, java-ee, push-notification, jwt

Estoy trabajando con un `webservice rest` en `java` en el cual los usuarios acceden a los datos de una `base de datos mysql`, la autenticación la había realizado con `JWT`.

Luego, buscando cómo enviar las notificaciones me topé con `Firebase` y veo que puedo implementar la autenticación, pero la duda que me surge es que teniendo en cuenta que al enviar el `token` de la manera que lo hacía al principio no lo almacenaba en mi `base de datos` sino que lo hacia el dispositivo en sus preferencias.

Ahora para enviarle la notificación uso `Firebase`, tendría que almacenar el token que le envío para asociarlo al usuario y así poder enviarle las `notificaciones` que desee(se las envío cuando hay algún cambio en la base de datos) o puedo en base a usuario y contraseña "consultarle" a `Firebase` qué token le dió para poder identificar qué usuario es y así enviarle su notificación?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ahora para enviarle la notificación uso Firebase, tendría que
>   almacenar el token que le envío para asociarlo al usuario y así poder
>   enviarle las notificaciones que desee

Si, si necesitas enviar notificaciones individuales deberías registrar el token de FCM en tu BD con el usuario. Ten en cuenta que estos tokens son renovados automáticamente cuando expiran y varian si el usuario ingresa en distintos dispositivos (deberías usar groups o topics de FCM para agruparlos).

> o puedo en base a usuario y contraseña "consultarle" a Firebase qué
>   token le dió para poder identificar qué usuario es

Esto no es posible ya que a menos que dupliques la lógica de auth no deberías tener usuario y contraseña de Firebase, sino solo el UID que firebase le asigna al usuario. Desgraciadamente actualmente firebase no permite (ni por API ni por consola) enviar notificaciones por UID :( .